# How to get MKMapView Directions in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13, xcode11

In my application I'm using MKMapView SwiftUI implementation. My map is working good but I want to get directions when tapped a button from ContentView. I've explained in more detail below...

Here is my ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AppleMapView(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7127, longitude: -74.0059))
            .frame(height: 400)

            Button(action: {
                **// !!! I want to call AppleMapView/getDirections() method here !!!**
            }) {
                Text("Get Directions")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my MapView:

```
struct AppleMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        // some codes //
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        // some codes //
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }

    func getDirections() {
        // some codes //
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.strokeColor = .blue
            renderer.lineWidth = 4
            return renderer
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you receiving? Why can't you call that function? We need more information to help.

Comment: I've updated the question. I think it is more understandable. Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `@Binding` property on your `MapView` and then set the `directions` from your `ContentView` inside the `Button` action.

This way your `updateUIView` will get called accordingly with the updated values.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var directions: [CLLocation] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView(directions: $directions)

            Button(action: {
                // Directions are Nepal to India
                self.directions = [CLLocation(latitude: 27.2041206, longitude: 84.6093928), CLLocation(latitude: 20.7712763, longitude: 73.7317739)]
            }) {
                Text("Get Directions")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var directions: [CLLocation]

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapView

        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.strokeColor = .blue
            renderer.lineWidth = 4
            return renderer
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        return MKMapView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        var coordinates = self.directions.map({(location: CLLocation!) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate})
        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: self.directions.count)

        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
    }
}
```